# Is there a way to set "window sizing area" size in WPF?

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-interface

By "window sizing area" I mean where user's mouse cursor changes into something like this <-> and it's possible to change window's width or height by dragging it's border.

Comment: Sorry for missunderstanding, I deleted my answer.

Comment: You must create a custom [`WindowChrome`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.shell.windowchrome?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Shell.WindowChrome)%3Bk(VS.XamlEditor)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=windowsdesktop-6.0#remarks). Then you can use the `WindowChrome.ResizeBorderThickness` property to adjust the border width.